# Dojo SyntaxError: missing ) in parenthetical

Tags: ajax, zend-framework, dojo, doctrine-1.2

I have had this same error before and posted a question to that effect but unfortunately there was no answer. The previous error occurred under different circumstances ( ie I was triggered when I used the dojo toolkit sdk(Size 19M).

This time I am retrieving data from a couple of tables which have a one to many relationship. I am using Dojo, Doctrine and Zend Framework for my project. I have posted quite an extensive error message at [1](http://pastie.org/1675243) the [Link to pastie.org with code and error details](http://pastie.org/1675243) and the php and javascript that I identified as being the code involved.

When you look towards the end of the pastie in the FIREBUG ERROR MESSAGE section you will see a piece of JSON like

```
[{"id":"000001",
"name":"Adam",
"area_id":null,
"registration_date":"2011-03-08",
"loan_cycle":"0","credit_score":"100",
"created_by":null,
    "borrowers":[{"id":"00000001",
        "first_name":"Test",
        "surname":"User",
        "dob":"2006-12-09",
        "personalid_no":"100000",
        "gender":"Male",
        "marital_status":"Marrie",
        "home_number":"09866678",
        "mobile_number":"09877655",
        "accomodation_type":"owner",
        "current_loan_cycle":"1",
        "status":"Active",
        "date_created":null,
        "date_registered":"2009-12-11",
        "created_by":null,
        "Groups_id":"000001"}]
}]
```

Its clear that the data gets pulled from the tables. However the code fails and I get the error message `SyntaxError: missing ) in parenthetical`. I have battled with this for a long time now. Am at a point where I either have to abandon the application or restart the whole project again. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you tried getting rid of the PHP error messages, such as:  Warning: include_once(Gepm\Model\GroupTable.php) [<a href='function.include-once'>function.include-once</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Comment: Well Ashley I have tried but without success so far. I am battling with that as well. I have been posting and chatting on IRC on end but so far I have not had any joy.

Comment: The PHP errors are what is causing you the javscript problems. You need to get rid of them first. Either remove the call to include_once(Gepm\Model\GroupTable.php) or create the file Gepm\Model\GroupTable.php